# Punctual Hilbert Scheme of three points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the Hilbert Scheme of zero dimensional, length 3 subschemes supported at the origin in $\mathbb A^2$. [Based on this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01389419#page-1) (click on Look Inside, the interesting part is on the second page), its even betti numbers are 1,1,1, so I think this should be irreducible of dimension 2.

How can I work out explicitly what it is? I'm trying, but I am getting something of dimension 1 with multiple components...

Comment: What do you get exactly? Have a look at [this link](http://math.mit.edu/~mckernan/Teaching/09-10/Spring/18.726/l_6.pdf), maybe this helps to get a start.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for.